# WPF - How to work out how much of a canvas background image is cropped?

Tags: wpf

I have a canvas with a background image:

```
var bi = new BitmapImage(new Uri(imgLocFull));           
var ib = new ImageBrush(bi) {Stretch = Stretch.UniformToFill};
MyCanvas.Background = ib;
```

I am overlaying various shapes on the image, and want the position of the shapes relative to the background image to be fixed.

If my application window is resized, the amount of the image that is cropped, horizontally and vertically, changes, and when my shapes are redrawn, they do not appear in the same position on the background image.

How can I determine how much of the image has been cropped (to apply an adjustment factor to the overlaid objects' positions?) Or is there a better way of fixing the location of a shape relative to the background image?

Here is my present drawing code:

```
var l = new Ellipse();
var scb = new SolidColorBrush();
scb.Color = Color.FromRgb(rCol, gCol, bCol);
l.Fill = scb;
l.StrokeThickness = 0;
l.Width = 3;
l.Height = 3;
Canvas.SetBottom(l, point.Y); // * clipping factor here?
Canvas.SetLeft(l, point.X);  // * clipping factor here?
MyCanvas.Children.Add(l);
```

EDIT: Further Clarification
Here's a concrete example of what I am trying to achieve. My image is an aerial photograph, and I want to mark a particular geographical feature (with, say, an ellipse.)

When the window is resized, the ellipse doesn't stay on the feature, it stays relative to the left and top of the canvas.

I can get it closer to the right place by moving it using a factor (`newx = newheight/oldheight * oldx`) but this doesn't quite work because of the `UniformToFill` stretch mode, which sees some of the image clipped off the canvas.

Comment: `Point.X` and `Point.Y` were calculated based on the size of the window prior to resizing. I now need to adjust them to cater for the resizing operation.

Answer (score 0):

The `Top` and `Left` of the `Canvas` are 'anchored', while the `Bottom` and `Right` move when resizing... try setting the `Canvas.Top Attached Property` instead, along with the `Canvas.Left Attached Property` as you are:

```
var l = new Ellipse();
var scb = new SolidColorBrush();
scb.Color = Color.FromRgb(rCol, gCol, bCol);
l.Fill = scb;
l.StrokeThickness = 0;
l.Width = 3;
l.Height = 3;
Canvas.SetTop(l, point.Y); // * clipping factor here?
Canvas.SetLeft(l, point.X);  // * clipping factor here?
MyCanvas.Children.Add(l);
```

---

UPDATE >>>

You asked *Or is there a better way of fixing the location of a shape relative to the background image?*

I answered this question, so I don't understand why you would need to do anything else... your objects will not move when the screen in resized *if you only set the `Grid.Top` and `Grid.Left` properties.

Comment: I accept that `Top` is better, but this doesn't resolve my problem. I need to know how much of my background image is clipped by the resizing operation.

Comment: No, but that's not what happens. When the image is resized, the overlaid objects stay where they are, and don't move with the image features. Setting .Top doesn't help.